# how to save p4 sync file locally with changelist number

Tags: perforce

I need to sync the P4 files on linux machine with changelist number and also save the file locally along with changelist number, say

file - abc#2003 should be copied to local machine as abc#2003

Thanks in advance

Comment: couldn't you just sync it back, then do a save? or in p4v open the revision you want, then do a save as of that file?

Comment: p4 print -o abc#2003 abc#2003

Comment: In my case the changelist number is random number and the script should take the current changelist number, save it on the local machine appending that current changelist number. For Ex:

Comment: ex: p4 sync //depot/myproject/file@changelist and print command as p4 print -o localfile@changelist //depot/myproject/file@changelist...does not save file with changelist number appended to it. I know I can predefine the changelist number but the purpose is to daily see the latest changelist, download the file and save it locally with changelist number..hope this clarifies the requirement

Comment: if this can be achieved through revision number then even that should be fine say..daily check the latest revision and download the file only when updated revision is available and save it locally with that revision number

Comment: You could do this using a script on your client machine, but if you rename a file, or make a copy of it with a different name, Perforce will either add this as a new file, or open it for move, depending on whether you run 'p4 add' or 'p4 reconcile'. If you do use a script to run a command such as 'p4 have' and make a copy of the file with the revision number appended, do not store it in the workspace. If you provide some more details about what you are aiming to achieve by doing this, there may be a better solution available.

Comment: Why?  I would love to know the reason for this slightly odd requirement

Comment: Here is the reason: we wanted to download the file from p4 to linux machine but before we download we wanted to ensure that this file is new file and my current file (local file on linux machine) is not the same as what I am trying to download. Since filename remain same with only incremental changelist number. If we download the file and keep it locally with changelist number, in next run if I try to download same file with same changelist number it can strait away throw the error saying file already present on local machine. Anyway we moved to using Java as it provides more API support